# Entity Framework June 2011 CTP And Unit Test Project

Tags: unit-testing, entity-framework, mstest

We have an MVC/EF project that we just upgraded to the June 2011 CTP. The web project is working great, the problem is, we can no longer reference it from the MSUnit project as it is targeting a newer Framework.

When I try to set the test project to target the June CTP it I get the below error:

> Attempted re-targeting of the project
>   has been canceled. To be able to
>   target your test project to .NET
>   Framework 3.5, you must use the steps
>   documented at the following Microsoft
>   Web site: 
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=201405.

After reading through it I can see it is specifically for .NET 3.5 .

Has anyone got any ideas how i can get my tests working?

Comment: What are the target frameworks of your web and test projects?

Comment: June CTP is an early preview. Its not recommended for production.

Comment: @Brian The web project targets the June 2011 CTP (it creates a new target framework) The test is targeting the .NET 4.0. This is where the problem is.

Comment: @Eranga The question is not related to production stability of the release, I'm trying to find out if unit testing is possible.

Comment: @tyrongower Sorry. I thought you upgraded an existing solution and got the error. You can report any bugs to https://connect.microsoft.com/dataplatform/content/content.aspx?ContentID=15541

Comment: Which version and edition of Visual Studio are you using?